# CodeIgniter : Fatal error: Call to private method CI_URI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I received a message in my website, the site was working correctly until we changed from SuPHP to FastCGI. I don't have any idea how to fix this problem. I have to change the code or I have to set different php values.

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Call to private method CI_URI::_parse_cli_args() from context 'MY_URI' in /home/tnbmobi/public_html/application/core/MY_URI.php on line 80

My code is as follows:

```
function _fetch_uri_string_2()
{
  if (strtoupper($this->config->item('uri_protocol')) == 'AUTO')
  {
    // Arguments exist, it must be a command line request
    if ( ! empty($_SERVER['argv']))
    {
      $this->uri_string = $this->_parse_cli_args();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear, _parse_cli_args is private, so you can't use that in your subclass MY_URI. If you really need that, copy the method code from /system/core/URI.php to MY_URI, rename the method name to my_parse_cli_args, and use $this->my_parse_cli_args instead.

Answer (score 0):

`_parse_cli_args` is private method resides in `CI_URI` class so you can't access that method from child class see this **[Visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)** for more information